# How look in a table and filter by the newest data available only

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

How do I look in a table and filter by only the newest data available?

My only solution so far is to sort the data decending, limit the job to only give me one record. Then I make the datetime stamp of that record into a variable then use that variable to filter the table again. With the sample data below the variable would become 29APR2022:00:00:00
But this solution is very slow, so I am looking for something better.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
per_dag;datetime;;;;Per_t;Per_N;Per_v;Per_C
144386;26APR2022:00:00:00;;;;117;26;26;5
144387;26APR2022:00:00:00;;;;118;27;27;6
144388;26APR2022:00:00:00;;;;119;28;28;7
144389;28APR2022:00:00:00;;;;120;29;29;1
144390;21APR2022:00:00:00;;;;121;30;30;2
144391;26APR2022:00:00:00;;;;122;31;1;3
144392;26APR2022:00:00:00;;;;123;32;2;4
144393;20APR2022:00:00:00;;;;124;33;3;5
144394;29APR2022:00:00:00;;;;125;34;4;6
144395;21APR2022:00:00:00;;;;126;35;5;7
```

This is what I ended up writing based on @draycut answer:

```
%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.QUERY_FOR_TXYZ1000FCT_000F);

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_TXYZ1000FCT_000F(label="WORK.QUERY_FOR_TXYZ1000FCT_000F") AS 
   SELECT t2.PERIODAG_D AS OpgoerelseDato, 
          t6.PERIODAG_D AS AfviklingDato, 
          t1.KILDEFACT_Key_I, 
          t3.X_ORDINATE, 
          t3.Y_ORDINATE, 
          t3.Z_ORDINATE, 
          t4.SKEMA_KODE, 
          t4.SKEMA_NAVN, 
          t5.KILDEFACT_NAVN, 
          t7.KUNDE_SCD_I, 
          t7.KONTO_SCD_I, 
          t2.PER_DAG_I
      FROM COREPLNZ.KXYZ1000FCT t1
           LEFT JOIN COREPLNZ.TKON0010PER_DAG_DIM t2 ON (t1.OPGOR_DAG_I = t2.PER_DAG_I)
           LEFT JOIN COREPLNZ.TKON0010PER_DAG_DIM t6 ON (t1.AFVIKL_DAG_I = t6.PER_DAG_I)
           LEFT JOIN COREPLNZ.KXYZ0090_SKEMA_JUNK t3 ON (t1.SKEMA_XYZ_JUNK_I = t3.SKEMA_XYZ_JUNK_I)
           LEFT JOIN COREPLNZ.TXYZ0100_SKEMA_DIM t4 ON (t1.SKEMA_I = t4.SKEMA_I)
           LEFT JOIN COREPLNZ.TXYZ0200_KILDEFACT_DIM t5 ON (t1.KILDEFACT_I = t5.KILDEFACT_I)
           LEFT JOIN COREPLNZ.KLIK6000_RESTLOEBETID_FCT t7 ON (t1.KILDEFACT_Key_I = t7.RESTLOEBETID_FCT_I)
      WHERE t5.KILDEFACT_NAVN = 'TLIK6000_RESTLOEBETID_FCT' AND t4.SKEMA_KODE = 'C 73.00'
      HAVING max(t2.PER_DAG_I) = t2.PER_DAG_I;
QUIT;
```

This works but it is still a bit slow for the large datasets I have.

Comment: have you tried adding an index on the datetime column? That should speed things up

Comment: How does an index work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
data have;
input per_dag datetime :anydtdtm. Per_t Per_N Per_v Per_C;
infile datalines dlm = ';';
format datetime datetime20.;
datalines4;
144386;26APR2022:00:00:00;117;26;26;5 
144387;26APR2022:00:00:00;118;27;27;6 
144388;26APR2022:00:00:00;119;28;28;7 
144389;28APR2022:00:00:00;120;29;29;1 
144390;21APR2022:00:00:00;121;30;30;2 
144391;26APR2022:00:00:00;122;31; 1;3 
144392;26APR2022:00:00:00;123;32; 2;4 
144393;20APR2022:00:00:00;124;33; 3;5 
144394;29APR2022:00:00:00;125;34; 4;6 
144395;21APR2022:00:00:00;126;35; 5;7 
;;;;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select * from have
   having max(datetime) = datetime
   ;
quit;
```